# VBScript To Remove Number from filename

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for a VBscript which scan a folder for files and remove number from filenames. for example if we have a file named "target1990.txt" then It should be "target.txt"

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RegExp that looks repeatedly/globally for a sequence of digits (\d+) and replace all matches with "" (nix):

```
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> s = "target1990.txt"
>> WScript.Echo s, r.Replace(s, "")
>>
target1990.txt target.txt
```

further sample (same regexp):

```
>> s = "t1ar33get19s90.txt"
>> WScript.Echo s, r.Replace(s, "")
>>
t1ar33get19s90.txt targets.txt
```

Comment: can u please write the whole script which scan a folder?

Comment: @Stranger, there are plenty of examples on this site showing how to iterate a folder (both single level and recursively). If you have a specific question about the process, please submit a new question.